# Números localizados nas posições ímpares

Tags: java, array

Eu deveria apresentar somente os números presentes nas posições ímpares do vetor, porém estou travado:

```
package pag1;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ex1 {

    public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner x = new Scanner (System.in);

        int posicao = 0;
        int[] numeros = new int[10];
        System.out.println("Digite 10 números inteiros seguidos:");

        while(posicao <= 9){
          numeros [posicao] = x.nextInt();
          posicao++;
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numeros));       
    }

 }
```

Na hora de mostrar apenas os números que estão nas posições ímpares não sei como, somente mostrar todas as posições do vetor.

Comment: Inicia o contador posicao a 1 e vais somando 2 em cada iteração, assim vais as posições 1, 3 ,5 ,7 ,9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faça um laço que comece da posição 1 do seu array e incremente de 2 em 2 até a posição 7:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ex1 {

    public static void main (String[] args){

        Scanner x = new Scanner (System.in);

        int posicao = 0;
        int[] numeros = new int[10];
        System.out.println("Digite 10 números inteiros seguidos:");

        while(posicao <= 9){
        numeros [posicao] = x.nextInt();
        posicao++;
        }

        for(int i = 1; i < numeros.length; i+=2){
            System.out.println("indice: " + i + " = " + numeros[i]);
        }             
    }    
 }
```

Veja em funcionamento no ideone: https://ideone.com/YWYb7p

Vale lembrar que arrays começam do indice 0, então o seu array vai de 0 a 9.

Comment: Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Para mostrar o valor impar ou par você pode utilizar da seguinte forma:

```java
valor % 2 == 0 // retorna true para valores pares
valor % 2 != 0 //retorna true para valores impares
```

Usando essa expressão dentro de um `if`, ele testa o retorno da divisão por dois é igual ou diferente de zero

Seu exemplo poderia ficar com a seguinte solução, utilizando `posicao` para retornar todos os valores nas posições impares ou `numeros[posicao]` para retornar todos os valores impares salvos no vetor:

```java
Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
int posicao = 0;
int[] numeros = new int[10];
while (posicao <= 9) {
   System.out.println("Digite o numero na possição vetor[" + posicao + "]:");
   numeros[posicao] = x.nextInt();
   posicao++;
}

posicao = 0;
while (posicao <= 9) {
    if (posicao % 2 != 0) {
        System.out.println("valor na posição impar do vetor:" + numeros[posicao]);
    }
    posicao++;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!